# Is there a way to use datauri as a file in input tags

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to use datauri as a file in `<input>`s? I have been searching for ways to do this but it just seems impossible. I tried something like this:

```
element.value = "data:image/png;base64,.......";
```

But then this of course yields a security error. Maybe transforming it into a blob will work? Or maybe emulating a DnD event?

Comment: It would be useful if you clarified what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @justinhoward - This is to directly inject programmatically produced files into input tags.

Comment: Depending on what you want to accomplish -- e.g. if you want to upload the file to the server, you can just put the base64 string in a hidden input field and let the server decode it.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Why do you want to assign data to a form field? The `FormData` API might suit your needs.

Comment: @RobW The `FormData` API lets me create a FormData object for XHR, but all I wanted is just to set the file and trigger its `change` event to let it do its thing. I can't directly send the request for it. Is there a way by changing the FormData object I can modify the real form in HTML?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 You can get a new modified form, but the original form remains unchanged.